# How far will Curiosty be removed from Perseverance?

Tags: mars, curiosity, perseverance, mapping

I'd like to know the distance between the Curiosity rover on Mars (currently at [Mount Sharp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Sharp), I believe) and the landing site of the Perseverance rover (the [Jezero crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jezero_(crater))). Is there an application or website like google maps that lets you calculate distances? Alternatively, where can I find a good map of the surface of Mars?

So far I only found detail traverse maps and high resolution pictures of the surface, but that's not really what I'm looking for. The picture below is close, but it has no distance scale.

I did a [calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#From_chord_length) based on the coordinates on Wikipedia (assuming a spherical planet *as usual*), which gives me 3584.12 km for the chord length and thus 1.1141576453620496...rad for the inner angle spanned by the two coordinates. This leads to a distance of 3776.44 km. I don't know if this is actually the distance between the two rovers...

[image]

Comment: Google Earth Pro (free) lets you switch to a Mars globe. https://www.google.com/earth/versions/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As OrganicMarble noted in the comments, Google Earth Pro has a nice map of Mars with all the rovers and landers included. And you can also measure distance. For example, here's the distance between Jezero Crater (left), and where Curiosity is in Gale Crater (right):

[image]

As you can see, your estimate was pretty close. Google Earth Pro shows 3717 km, and your estimate was 3776 km.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know how to do it.